# "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" in chess program

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am writing a chess program and in my code I keep running into this error in my function. this is occurring in the third to last line.
The full traceback is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\chess2.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    buttons=(tk.Button(self.boardframe, padx=10,  text=self.placepieces(pos), borderwidth=0, bg=colour,  relief="solid", font=self.piecefont, command=lambda position=pos: self.movepiece(position)  ))
  File "C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\chess2.py", line 73, in movepiece
    if self.newsquare in movelist:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Where the buttons are defined:

```py
    def drawboard(self):

        x=0
        y=0
        for column in range(self.n):
            self.changecolours()
            x=x+1
            y=0
            for row in range(self.n):
                y=y+1
                colour = self.colours[self.colourindex]
                pos=(x,9-y)
                buttons=(tk.Button(self.boardframe, padx=10,  text=self.placepieces(pos), borderwidth=0, bg=colour,  relief="solid", font=self.piecefont, command=lambda position=pos: self.movepiece(position)  ))
                buttons.grid(column=(x-1), row=(y-1), sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S" )
                self.changecolours()
```

```py
    def movepiece(self, squareposition):
        player=Game().player
        turn=Game().turn
        if self.square==(-10,-10):
            self.square=squareposition
            if self.square in player.position.values()==True:
                for key in player.position:
                    pieceposition=player.position.get(key)
                    if self.square==pieceposition:
                        self.piece=key
                        break
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                self.gamelabel.config(text="Error no " +str(turn)+" piece on this square please try again")
                self.square==(-10,-10)

        else:
            self.newsquare=squareposition
            if self.newsquare==self.square:
                self.square=(-10,-10)
                self.newsquare=(-11,-11)
                self.gamelabel.config(text=str(turn)+" to move")
            else:
                movelist=player.moves.get(self.piece)
                if self.newsquare in movelist:
                   self.square=(-10,-10)
                   self.newsquare=(-11,-11)
```

Comment: That error means that `player.moves.get(self.piece)` is returning None. Without any additional code, we cannot debug why it is returning None.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your getting this error because the key you are trying to access in the `player.moves` either does not exist, or the value of the key is `None`. You can get around this by performing a sanity check to make sure `movelist` is not `None`

```py
if movelist and self.newsquare in movelist:
   self.square=(-10,-10)
   self.newsquare=(-11,-11)
```